# How to create an array of permissions in Kotlin similar to how it's done in Java?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

This is what it looks like in *Java*:

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,               
                                 android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,   
                                 android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                 android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}
```

This is what I have where it is being treated as 4 separate expression and I cannot figure out how to make an array of these contents in *Kotlin*.

```
    private val PERMISSIONS = Array<String>(4) { android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;               
                                 android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;   
                                 android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                                 android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO }
```

Comment: Use `arrayOf(item1, item2, etc)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Kotlin* it would be

```
private val PERMISSIONS: Array<String> = arrayOf(
            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    )
```